# What does *arr[] mean?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

i have this code from my previous exam and it's the first time I  see this `*arr[]`.  What does that mean? Is it a matrix or an array?
And what does it contain?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f2(int **a, int x, int y);
int main()
{
  int m[3][4] = {{7,12,11,21 }, {20,1,2,3}, {33,42,11,50}};
  int *arr[] = { m[0], m[1], m[2] };
  f2(arr, 3, 4);
  _getch();
  return 0;
}

void f2(int **a, int x, int y)
{
  if (x > 0)
  {
    int i, j = 0, *p = a[x - 1];
    for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
      if (!(p[i] % 3))
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
    }
    f2(a, x - 1, y);
  }
  else
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: That's a beginner's question really.You can learn that in the initial pages of any decent C book.

Comment: @machine_1 oh really if a "beginner's question" bothers you, you can simply ignore it!

Comment: It helps the search process on google go faster, i believe many other beginners have this question as well. This could be a quick search for help!

Answer (score 7):

> what does `*arr[]` mean?

As standalone expression `*arr[]` is not valid.

For variable definitions there are two meanings here, depending of the context in which such an expression appears:

1. *Variable definition with initialiser (as per the OP's snippet)*

   ```
   int * arr[] = { m[0], m[1], m[2] };
   ```

   This defines an array of *pointer* to `int`, with its number of elements being determined by the number of elements in its initialiser. In the above example `arr` will have three elements.
2. *Variable definition inside a function's parameter list*

   If used like like this, that is inside a function declaration/definition

   ```
   void foo(int * arr[]);
   ```

   it in fact defines an `int **`, a *pointer* to *pointer* to `int`. In the context of a function declaration/definition `int * arr[]` and `int ** arr` are equivalent, or more general `T*[]` equals `T**`.

To explicitly state this: *In **no** case `int * arr[]` defines any `int`s.*

Comment: is it filled with numbers? if yes what are they

Comment: size of what? The number of elements is three, as indicated by the initializers. sizeof(arr) is the number of bytes in a pointer.

Comment: @lasvegasnay "*it*": who? The array's elements? Yes, by the value as given by the initialiser: `{ m[0], m[1], m[2] };`

Comment: @nicomp: Clarified the wording.

Comment: @alk : Is  `array of pointer`  preferred to `array of pointers`?

Comment: @sjsam: "array of integer" vs. "array of integers": I prefer the former, because the latter *could* be interpreted in the way that each array's element might contain "integers", that is more then exactly one "integer", which definitely isn't the case. Also "array of integer" is in line with what actually is coded: `int a[42]`. From the perspective of English grammar "array of integer" might be wrong. I feel the plural already comes with "array".

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
int *arr[] = { m[0], m[1], m[2] };
```

declares `arr` as an array of pointers to `int`; the size of the array is determined by the number of initializers (3).  It's the same thing as writing

```
int *arr[3];
arr[0] = m[0];
arr[1] = m[1];
arr[2] = m[2];
```

Each initializer (`m[0]`, `m[1]`, and `m[2]`) is a 4-element array of `int`; however, under most circumstances, an *expression* of type "array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array, so the above line is equivalent to

```
int *arr[] = { &m[0][0], &m[1][0], &m[2][0] };
```

Each element in `arr` is a *pointer* to an int, not an array of int.  Because of how array subscripting in C works, `arr[i][j]` will give you the same result as `m[i][j]`.

Answer (score 1):

By the statement

```
int *arr[]; // int* arr[] is also true but stick on to one format.
```

you declare an array of pointers to integers.

Demystifying :

```
int m[3][4] = {{7,12,11,21 }, {20,1,2,3}, {33,42,11,50}};
```

- `m` is an array.
- `m[0]`,`m[1]`,`m[2]` points to `int[4]`. Point #A
- `m[0][0]` is an integer.

From point **#A** it is understood that `m[0]`,`m[1]`,`m[2]` are pointers.
Demystifying :

```
int *arr[] = { m[0], m[1], m[2] };
```

- `arr[0]`,`arr[1]`,`arr[2]` are assigned to  `m[0], m[1], m[2]` respectively.
- `m[1][2]` is equivalent to `arr[1][2]`.

Comment: @alk : Did I say `arr` has a type? Pardon me, I didn't get you

Comment: I read "*declare*" as "*define*", which is not the same, sry.